# Sheafification of a given presheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a presheaf on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is the abelian group of continuous functions with bounded support on $U$. Then what is the sheafification of $\mathcal{F}$?

I guess the sheafification should be the abelian group of continuous functions, but how should I prove it rigorously?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mathcal{F}$ is not a presheaf : if $s\in\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})$ has support in $[0,1]$, then $s|_{(0,1)}$ does not have compact support.

Comment: @Roland I fixed the statement: the support is not necessarily compact, it is just bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ be our presheaf of continuous functions with bounded support, $G$ be the sheaf of continuous functions, $F^+$ the sheafification of $F$.

Every continuous function with bounded support is a continuous function, so we have an injective morphism $F\to G$, which induces a map $F^+\to G$ by definition of the sheafification. To show that this is an isomorphism, we just need to prove that it is an isomorphism on stalks. However, $F^+$ has the same stalks as $F$, so it suffices to prove that the map $F\to G$ induces an isomorphism on stalks.

However, this is fairly clear. We already know injectivity, so it just remains to check surjectivity. Pick $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Choose $U$ some bounded open neighborhood of $\Bbb{R}$. Then for any $[(f,W)]\in G_x$, we have that the class $[(f|_{W\cap U},W\cap U)]\in F_x$ maps to $[(f,W)]$.

Comment: @anonymous_downvoter If there is an error in this answer, I would appreciate a comment so that I could improve my answer.